# How to add a service dependency to NServiceBus Generic Host

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, msmq, nservicebus

I have the following services Layout:

- **Interface Service** (generates commands from WCF requests, TCP requests, Polling, etc.)
- **Worker Service** (consumes commands generated by interface service and publishes events)
- **Event Handler Service** (handles events generated by worker service)

I am using the MSMQ Subscription storage.

My current problem is that I have to start the **event handler service** *after* the **worker service** is started. If I do it in reverse, or restart the **worker service** publications won't be received by the **event handler service**.

My first idea is to add a service dependency on the **event handler service**.

How would I do this using the generic host provided by NServiceBus? Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the DB subscription option.  This will keep your subscriptions around.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MSMQ as subscription storage then make the subscription queue transactional.

Then the subscription messages from the event handler service will remain on the worker service subscription queue even after restarting.

Regarding start up order, the event handler service will put a subscription into the input queue of the worker service, whether or not the worker services is started. So the start up order is also unimportant.

**UPDATE**

Actually this is strictly untrue, because making the queues transactional will give you durability across server restarts.

You should still get the same behaviour I described above with non-transactional queues.

Comment: I'll try to make the queues transactional. I have to add `.IsTransactional(true)` to the fluent config, right?

Comment: Yes, or derive from AsA_Server. However, I realised something, see update to my original answer.

Comment: I changed the IsTransactional property around but it seems not to change. I'll investigate this problem more deeply tomorrow.